# Every major video streaming app stopped working collectively on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, streaming, netflix

YouTube, Netflix, Amazon Prime, Disney+ among others aren't loading video on my iPhone and many user's updated iOS. And I'm trying to get to the bottom as much as I can to contribute to solve the issue (as it doesn't seem to be acknowledged much), but I don't know where to begin. I felt like it's DNS issue but it also doesn't seem like so. I haven't tested this yet, but I wanted to do it in right order, so can someone shed some light on this?

I do have the latest XCode on Mac, so I can connect to terminal and copy all the message I found on console - but I also do not know where to submit this information. Does Apple only gather feedback of the sort through developer community?

---

So here's what's happening:

Currently, I'm experiencing an issue on my iPhone that is reported in many places though seemingly getting no resolution for about a month.

I'm using iOS 16.1.1 running on iPhone 12 mini, and none of video streaming services are working. That includes YouTube, Amazon Prime (and abemaTV - sort of hulu of Japan). Other reports I see online indicates that it's been happening since iOS 16.1.0 update on numerous devices, including other major apps like Netflix and Disney+ as well! It sounds a bit crazy to me that all these big apps stopped working on many devices, although it seems like it's not happening to demographics large enough.

It resolves after every reboots, and I don't know how long, but many reports that the issue will come back after a certain time. Some other says that resetting network configuration will fix the issue as well, but then it'll come back later anyways.

Watching YouTube on browser does work as expected, however on app:

1. Tap on video to play
2. On most of the video (*), it'll show the first faint moment of advertisement clip with the ad skip countdown timer on the right bottom
3. It blacks out and shows error message that reads "Something went wrong" but nothing more than that. ([You can find a image reference here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/y36oe3/youtube_keeps_saying_something_went_wrong_closing/))

*: There are some video that plays fine, and I don't know what makes it able to be played. All I can tell is that all videos that I could watch didn't play ad, so I'm guessing it has something to do with advertisements.

Amazon Prime was similar: They do show a few frames of the contents, but instead of going straight into the error message, the image gets distorted for a few seconds like a broken TV. Therefore I must guess that this has to do with something on OS level rather than implementation issue on app side. Here's a few other reports: [Apple developers community](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719969?login=true&page=1&r_s_legacy=true#737307022), [YouTube help](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/187452057/youtube-app-videos-not-playing-on-ios-something-went-wrong?hl=en)

What annoys me is that it will always show a tiny bit of a clip, so it doesn't seem as though it's having connecting issue. And on top of that, rebooting will always temporarily fix the issue. I initially thought this could be a DNS issue, but can it still be that??

I'm setting up debugging on XCode - and since I had to reboot my iOS to get there, I can play every video, although this should be temporary fix. So once it stopped working, I'd like to gather some information. But I really don't know where to start.

---

I have absolutely no experience in developing iOS app or using XCode. I did figured how to extract messages on console from my physical device, but I don't know what to do. Should I submit the entire console message from a few second before I tap the video until the error messsage shows up? But where to?

Comment: Are you using the specific apps for these services (YouTube, Netflix, etc) or using a web browser like Safari, Firefox, Google Chrome?

Comment: @IconDaemon Nope, I am using each official app. And as said, it works from browser (such as using Chrome to access youtube.com instead of using YouTube official app). It's well more than half a day ever since I rebooted and it's still working, which should be well over the average TTL for DNS so I'm pretty lost unless the issue is 'magically' solved.

Comment: I guess, just like psychotherapy, talking about it helps. :-)

Comment: @IconDaemon Why does it always magically go away just when I started to pay attention.. It's almost like I'm begging for the bug to come back haha

Comment: I've been doing tech support in a school for decades. Half the time I arrive to troubleshoot, the problem has disappeared.